# Single or multiple Dropbox Business API connections?

Tags: dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox Business API to extract folders/files.  However, it is taking some time (can get 10 folders deep).
So I am thinking to run the process with multiple computers, say four computers per  1/4 members' records each.

1. Will it be OK to run all the four processes over one Dropbox Business API connection?
2. Should create four different Dropbox Business API connections and run those processes per different connections?
3. It doesn't matter either way?

Let me know if you have any idea.
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you elaborate on the original issue? (Your stated question here is a little vague, but to try to answer it anyway: it probably wouldn't matter.)

Comment: Thanks, Greg.  I created separate connections and run separately.

Answer (score 0):

I created multiple Dropbox API connections and run processes per connections instead of running processes on one API connection.